Raspberry Pi Connect. No hash when using alt 3 from a mac
Ive just started using Raspberry Pi Connect with a RPI5 and the latest OS. Im writing Python code and want to comment it by starting lines with a hash.  However the usual way of writing a hash, alt + 3, simply writes the number 3.  It works as you would expect when writing # on a document (like this one) but not when using Raspberry Pi Connect.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you respond what version of macOS you’re using or how this relates to Apple, please?

This is a bug with Raspberry Pi Connect.
There are various suggestions on https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=11761,

ctrl + alt + 3
ctrl + 3
right alt + 3

that may work depending on your locale.
